# Pagination with Dropbox

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have to implement a pageable grid with listed Dropbox files and I need these two functions:
- offset
- limit

I know I can use `ListFolderGetLatestCursorBuilder` for setting the limit but how can I achieve offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API `ListFolder` functionality doesn't offer a way to request a specific offset in the results. You should use [`listFolderContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolderContinue-java.lang.String-) to call repeatedly as necessary to get all of the results to match the server state. Be sure to review [the `listFolder` documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#listFolder-java.lang.String-) to see how to process the results in order to get an accurate representation.